# elementary complex analysis question (Cauchy-Riemann conditions)

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm asking the following because I haven't yet found an entirely satisfactory answer elsewhere on the internet for this, despite the fact that it seems like it should be relatively easy to find...maybe I'm just not looking hard enough, but, hey, free points for you, right? Anyway, my question is really straightforward. What are the appropriate equivalent(s) of the Cauchy-Riemann conditions for functions like

$$
h(u,v,w) = f(u,v,w) + ig(u,v,w)
$$

rather than the usual $f(u,v) + ig(u,v)$? Pardon my ignorance and many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this answers your question - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Several_variables.

Also, see http://dmle.cindoc.csic.es/pdf/GACETAMATEMATICA_1978_30_05-06_03.pdf. See also http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/048/5/V48.N05.A07.pdf, though the pages are blurry.

Comment: Could you please contextualize this for me? I mean, I understand how to use Wirtinger derivatives properly, but, how do I turn them into the appropriate version of the CR conditions...? I was looking more for an explicit set of equations...

Comment: @Nicola See my edited answer.

Comment: These were both exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @Nicola {}{}{}{} Sure!